# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error at next.js production on ec2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, next.js

I deployed my next.js app on the ec2 instance with server app(express)
and connected them to the domain with ssl certification.

I get this error continuously.

this is my next.config.js
I'm using app Dir, and serverAction for cookie.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true, // Next에게 styled-component도 처리해달라고 옵션을 >설정해줌
  },
};

module.exports = {
  output: "standalone",
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
    appDir: true,
  },
  ...nextConfig,

};
```

[image: next.config.js]

And my nginx config file .

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {
        listen 443;

 #location /_next/static {
         #       alias /home/ubuntu/ophthal-front/.next/static;
        #        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, immutable";
       # }
#I tried but didn't work so i just made it comment.



        location / {


        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

}

    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;  # Remove /api prefix
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084;
    }
}
```

When I enter the https://example.com I get this error

[image]
[image]

Also, there is a input filed and button clickable in my page
but i can't even click it. (no response)

Can somebody help me out with this? :(

I tried adding these lines below to nginx config file

```
 #location /_next/static {
         #       alias /home/ubuntu/ophthal-front/.next/static;
        #        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, immutable";
       # }
```

and also

```
assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://example.com' : undefined,
```

this line to the next.config.js

And I cleared caches and cookies but the problem remained the same.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it? I need it, I am also facing the same issue